# If $f:]0,a[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is diff. with $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}f'(x)=c$ then $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}f(x)/x=c$

Tags: real-analysis

I am not familiar with lhospialrule and everything after that, please consider this in your answer

I have tried to first look at $c=0$ with an estimate by employing the triangleequality $|f(x)/x|\leq (|f(x)-f(x_0)|/x)+f(x_0)/x$ in combination with the fact that there exists a $x_0$ such that $|f'(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\leq x_0$ in conjuncture with a corollary that if the derivative is bounded then the secant is a also bounded (i.e. $\forall x\in ]a,b[:|f'(x)|\leq\epsilon\Rightarrow \forall x_1\leq x_2\in [a,b]:f(x_2)-f(x_1)\leq \epsilon(x_2-x_1)$). But it didnt work out. I also dont know how to use that $\lim_{x\downarrow0}f(x)=0$.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ you can define the extended function $F: [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ via 
$$
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if }x >0 \\
0 &\text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $F$ is continuous on $[0,1)$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$.  By the mean-value theorem, for $0 < x <1$,
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{F(x) - F(0)}{x -0} = f'(y)
$$
for some $0 < y < x$.  From this and the fact that $f'(x) \to c$ as $x \to 0$ we can readily deduce that $f(x)/x \to c$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks alot. problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. There is a $\delta>0$ such that$$x\in(0,\delta)\implies \bigl\lvert f'(x)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon.\tag1$$Now, extend $f$ to $[0,a)$ by putting $f(0)=0$. Then, $f$ is continuous and it is differentiable on $(0,\delta)$. Then, by the mean value theorem, if $x\in(0,\delta)$,$$\frac{f(x)}x=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=f'(c).$$Then, by $(1)$, $\bigl\lvert f'(c)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$. So,$$\left\lvert\frac{f(x)}x\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$